# Wireshark hex dump analyzer possible to do in Java?

Tags: java, hex, wireshark

I have a pcap file and I can view the hex and human-readable string equivalent of the hexdump using wireshark. However, I want to do the same but in Java. Here is a screenshot from Wireshark application.

[image]

Taking the highlighted string, this is what i've come but the output is not what I've expect. Can someone help me? Thank you very much

```
    String hex = "a106020110020138";
    byte[] bts = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bts.length; i++) {
      bts[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
    }  
    String c = new String(bts, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    System.out.println(c);
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this library? I haven't used it but it seems to be able to read pcaps. https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j

Comment: What output *did* you expect, then? Wireshark does *not* convert to a "human-readable string equivalent", all it does is show characters within displayable ASCII range (space up to tilde) as characters, and all others as periods. An *extremely* common way to display raw binary data.

Comment: @johncip, i just used pcap files to show what i want to achieve, but technically what I will receive are hex dumps.

Comment: @Jongware, I want to see the "GSM Mobile Application", "Component: invoke (1)", etc.,  possibly all the details that Wireshark provides. Is that possible?

Comment: Hm. Don't really know then. Looking at tshark might help, it is a command-line version of Wireshark and it can do the actual capturing and then decode the data into something readable.

Comment: The Wireshark strings are an *interpretation* of the binary data, not some sort of character/byte encoding. See the example in the [TCAP entry in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_Capabilities_Application_Part)

Comment: @Jongware, thanks for the clarification. Do you know how the data is interpreted? Any links/tutorials you can give? The entry in Wikipedia was not enough to understand this "interpretation" of binary data. Thank you very much

Comment: The literature under the Wikipedia article point to the official ITU specifications. Reading Q.773 would be a good start, I suppose -- at a quick glance, it appears to outline the binary format of TCAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses UTF-16 for characters, in what byte order i forgot, meaning you need to use two bytes per character.

Comment: change you code to make the byte array hex.length() instead of hex.length/2 and then write in bts[2*i] or bts[2*i+1]. Which one is correct depends on the byte order of the JVM, which i am unsure of atm. No, i won't post code, and no, i can't test my answer at the moment. I feel my answer is enough to figure the problem out, despite downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to look exactly like Wireshark's, you can do by reading each group of two hex digits, and keeping that ones that correspond to printable ASCII characters:

```
public class Pcap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "701c2f676c08a106020110020138";

        int n = hex.length();
        char[] cs = new char[n / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2)
            cs[i/2] = (char) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i+2), 16);

        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++)
            if (cs[i] < ' ' || cs[i] > '~') // printable ASCII
                cs[i] = '.';

        System.out.println(new String(cs));

    }
}
```

which outputs

`p./gl........8`

However, my guess is that you're better off using a library that can parse pcaps (I mentioned one earlier, it looks like http://jpcap.sourceforge.net might also work), since just getting that hex string in the first place required opening Wireshark. You can write the code yourself to pull those values from the (binary) pcap file, but projects already exist to do that.

Comment: the hex dump will actually be coming from reading a ss7 dialogic card that contains data similar to wireshark representation.